# PHP 5.4 APC/Session upload progress under php-fpm

Tags: nginx, apc, php

I am running nginx with php5-fpm, I've installed APC and tried to use it and also tried session upload progress since my php 5.4.16 allows it. But I don't get any progress returning cached data (looks like it waits until php ends processing it). Does apc even work under php5-fpm? How to make this work uder fast-cgi?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reading forums I've found, that APC on nginx works, just it will not buffer the download progress.

So the solution would be to use Nginx upload progress module.

Answer (score 0):

First of all yes it does work under php5-fpm, I have a website on my laptop with which uses nginx and php-fpm and it worked fine, but to make sure you can check the `phpinfo()`.

Could you please explain the cycle of the data, how you set it and how it gets read ?, and just in case, apc data that's saved by `php-cli` can't be accessed by the web, and also the one that's set by a web page can't be accessed by cli.

Comment: Well what I've tried so far, is installed APC, in phpinfo it is set fine, enabled, prefix and name also corresponds with php apc upload progress but I still not get received values by the server, progress bar does not work. The same is with session progress upload under 5.4, even it has nothing to do with APC maybe then something wrong is on the php5-fpm side or nginx? I never used APC, nor SESSION upload before, so I'm not sure what could be wrong.